# Alignment in Vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin

I have the following piece of code that I wrote in Vaadin.

The problem is that the alignment does not work. I set it to bottom_center, but the components are all stuck to the top (top_center) of my web browser.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Thanks!

```
    VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
    VerticalLayout layout1 = new VerticalLayout();
    Panel panel = new Panel();
    panel.setWidth("500px");
    panel.setHeight("300px");

    Button button = new Button("Enter");
    Button login = new Button("Login");

    layout1.addComponent(textfield);
    layout1.addComponent(button);
    layout1.addComponent(login);
    layout.addComponent(panel);

    layout.setComponentAlignment(panel, Alignment.BOTTOM_CENTER);
    layout1.setComponentAlignment(textfield, Alignment.BOTTOM_CENTER);
    layout1.setComponentAlignment(login, Alignment.BOTTOM_CENTER);
    layout1.setComponentAlignment(button, Alignment.BOTTOM_CENTER);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason for the components appering to be aligned to the top is that you haven't specified a height for your VerticalLayouts. When you don't specify a size for a layout, its size is determined by the child components it contains. In such a case, setting the alignment won't make any difference, as there's no extra room inside the layout's slots.

Set the size, using e.g. `layout.setHeight("100%");` or `layout.setSizeFull();` and you should notice the difference immediately.

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify a height for the layout so it'll expand from the top towards the bottom as it needs with each component you add. If you set `layout.setHeight("100%");` the components will be aligned at the bottom.

Answer (score -1):

you mus set setSizeUndefined() to your panel, textfield, login, button component
and setSizeFull layout1.